# How can I retrieve the heart beats during a period of time using HKHeartbeatSeriesSample?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos

I'm trying to get the underlying heart beat data from healthStore based on this conference at the  [WWDC 2019 - Exploring new Data Representations in HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/218/). At mark 24:40 is explained how HealthKit has a sensor capable of storing the exact timestamps of the beats and this data is accessible through the HKHeartbeatSeriesSample type.

I've created this query to retrieve that data:

```swift
func queryData(start: Date, end: Date) {
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: start, end: end, options: [])
    
    let heartBeatSeriesSample = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKSeriesType.heartbeat(), predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: nil) {
        (query, results, error) in
        
        guard let samples = results, let sample = samples.first as? HKHeartbeatSeriesSample else {
            print("Failed: no samples collected")
            return
        }
        print(results as Any)
        
        let heartBeatSeriesQuery = HKHeartbeatSeriesQuery(heartbeatSeries: sample) {
            (query, timeSinceSeriesStart, precededByGap, done, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Failed querying the raw heartbeat data: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            print(timeSinceSeriesStart)
        }
        self.healthStore?.execute(heartBeatSeriesQuery)
    }
    healthStore?.execute(heartBeatSeriesSample)
}
```

But it only works if I use no predicate, which then shows all heartbeat data stored previously, but during the time period nothing is stored.
I've managed to store some data using the `HKHeartbeatSeriesBuilder` the following way:

```swift
let builder = HKHeartbeatSeriesBuilder(
    healthStore: self.healthStore!,
    device: .local(),
    start: start
)

builder.addHeartbeatWithTimeInterval(sinceSeriesStartDate: 0.5, precededByGap: false) {
    (success, error) in

    guard success else {
        fatalError("Could not add heartbeat: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

It stored the data and not the actual beats read by the Apple Watch device. Since I would need the actual beats to store them this way, then there must be a query that gives me that data before I have to store it in the first place (classic chicken and the egg).

How can I read the exact heart beats with timestamps during a given period of time?

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Unfortunately it is not possible to extract the raw data with the apple watch alone. I opened a ticket in apple developer support and they said the advertised features were possible, using a third party device. Very disappointing and for sure not chosing Apple for a serious project like this in the future.